# Grouping an array by spreading another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Previously, structure of my array was:

```
[
  {
    "id": "Ddfwe23224533",
    "kind": "PEAK_EXPERIENCE",
    "title": "IP - Collective Identity",
  },
  {
    "id": "Ddfwe23224534",
    "kind": "PEAK_EXPERIENCE",
    "title": "IP - Collective Identity 2",
  },
  .....
]
```

I have created a function called flatToHierarchy to group the elements in an array. Here is the code:

```
export const flatToHierarchy = (arr, prop) => arr.reduce((accumulator, currentItem) => {
  const items = accumulator;
  const propValue = currentItem[prop];
  items[propValue] = items[propValue]
    ? [...items[propValue], currentItem]
    : [currentItem];
  return items;
}, {});
```

Now if I call it like:

```
flatToHierarchy(elements, 'kind')
```

It works fine.

---

Now, structure of my array is changed. Now it looks like:

```
[
  {
    "entity": {
      "id": "Ddfwe23224533",
      "kind": "PEAK_EXPERIENCE",
      "title": "IP - Collective Identity",
    },
    entity_id: "jj98834jfj983"
  },
  {
    "entity": {
      "id": "Ddfwe23224534",
      "kind": "PEAK_EXPERIENCE",
      "title": "IP - Collective Identity 2",
    },
    entity_id: "jj98834jfdf83"
  },
  .....
]
```

So, now for grouping array by element kind, I call it this way:

```
flatToHierarchy(elements, 'entity.kind')
```

Now, it yields me something like:

```
{
  undefined: [....element1, ....element2 ]
}
```

But what I want is:

```
{
  PEAK_EXPERIENCE: [....element1, ....element2 ]
}
```

I have dug deeper in to this and found that array cannot be accessed this way:

```
array['something.something']
```

It needs to be accessed this way:

```
array['something']['something']
```

So, I changed my function but I am stuck. Here is my changed function:

```
export const flatToHierarchy = (arr, prop) => arr.reduce((accumulator, currentItem) => {
  const items = accumulator;
  const props = prop.split('.').map(p => [p]);
  console.log(props);
  const propValue = currentItem[prop];
  console.log(currentItem...props); // how to spread the array here?
  items[propValue] = items[propValue]
    ? [...items[propValue], currentItem]
    : [currentItem];
  return items;
}, {});
```

**Update:**

Sample of current input:

```
[
  {
    "entity": {
      "id": "Ddfwe23224533",
      "kind": "PEAK_EXPERIENCE",
      "title": "IP - Collective Identity",
    },
    entity_id: "jj98834jfj983"
  },
  {
    "entity": {
      "id": "Ddfwe23224534",
      "kind": "PEAK_EXPERIENCE",
      "title": "IP - Collective Identity 2",
    },
    entity_id: "jj98834jfdf83"
  },
  {
    "entity": {
      "id": "Ddfwe23224594",
      "kind": "PEAK_EXPERIENCE2",
      "title": "IP - Collective Identity 6",
    },
    entity_id: "jj98834jfdf33"
  },
]
```

sample of needed output:

```
{
  PEAK_EXPERIENCE: [
    {
      "entity": {
        "id": "Ddfwe23224533",
        "kind": "PEAK_EXPERIENCE",
        "title": "IP - Collective Identity",
      },
      entity_id: "jj98834jfj983"
    },
    {
      "entity": {
        "id": "Ddfwe23224534",
        "kind": "PEAK_EXPERIENCE",
        "title": "IP - Collective Identity 2",
      },
      entity_id: "jj98834jfdf83"
    },
  ],
  PEAK_EXPERIENCE2: [
    {
      "entity": {
        "id": "Ddfwe23224594",
        "kind": "PEAK_EXPERIENCE2",
        "title": "IP - Collective Identity 6",
      },
      entity_id: "jj98834jfdf33"
    },
  ],
}
```

**Update 2:**

While making changes to the required function, I need to keep in mind that this function will always have the signature as specified below:

```
flatToHierarchy(array, string);
```

example:

```
flatToHierarchy(elements, 'kind');
```

another example:

```
flatToHierarchy(elements, 'entity.kind');
```

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. Could you please post a sample of the input (which i think is there) and one of final output that you're looking for.

Comment: @rmn I have included the samples in update part of the question. Please have a look at them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a `path` function, which you can make by using `reduce` and seeding with the initial object.

Watch out for `null`/`undefined` properties!

```
const propValue = prop
  .split('.') // Make a list of all property names (cannot contain a .)
  .reduce((obj, p) => obj[p], currentItem); // Loop over them to traverse your object
```

```js
const flatToHierarchy = (arr, prop) => arr.reduce((accumulator, currentItem) => {
  const items = accumulator;
  const propValue = prop.split('.').reduce((obj, p) => obj[p], currentItem);
  items[propValue] = items[propValue]
    ? [...items[propValue], currentItem]
    : [currentItem];
  return items;
}, {});

const data = [
  {
    "entity": {
      "id": "Ddfwe23224533",
      "kind": "PEAK_EXPERIENCE",
      "title": "IP - Collective Identity",
    },
    entity_id: "jj98834jfj983"
  },
  {
    "entity": {
      "id": "Ddfwe23224534",
      "kind": "PEAK_EXPERIENCE",
      "title": "IP - Collective Identity 2",
    },
    entity_id: "jj98834jfdf83"
  },
  {
    "entity": {
      "id": "Ddfwe23224594",
      "kind": "PEAK_EXPERIENCE2",
      "title": "IP - Collective Identity 6",
    },
    entity_id: "jj98834jfdf33"
  },
]

console.log(
  flatToHierarchy(data, "entity.kind")
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your sample input is in a variable called *data*, you can do the following.

```
data = data.reduce((output, current) => {
    const kind = current.entity.kind
    output[kind] = (output[kind] || []).concat(current)
    return output
}, {})
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But entity.kind will not be known. It will be passed to function call. Look at the update 2 part of the question.

Comment: Got it. What happens when the *string* is just 'kind' as in your first example. Since, there's no 'kind', just 'entity.kind', will it fail?

Comment: it will return an empty array.

Comment: For anyone referencing it in future, since the question was updated, please see [the correct answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52221646/2206733).